# Gradle build not working libGDX Javahome wrong

Tags: java, android, libgdx, java-home

I've been trying to get libGDX to work out but i always get a error when gradle's building.

here is the error

```
Gradle sync failed: The newly created daemon process has a different context than expected.
        It won't be possible to reconnect to this daemon. Context mismatch: 
        Java home is different.
        Wanted: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=null,javaHome=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2\jre,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Shawn\.gradle\daemon,pid=396,idleTimeout=null,daemonOpts=-Xms128m,-Xmx1500m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
        Actual: DefaultDaemonContext[uid=be8febdd-0d00-4ec8-98ce-6076e4f5a2eb,javaHome=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111,daemonRegistryDir=C:\Users\Shawn\.gradle\daemon,pid=9116,idleTimeout=60000,daemonOpts=-Xms128m,-Xmx1500m,-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

My project Structure
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esMFU.png)

build.gradle file

[Java home isn't defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufa5y.png)

---

Solved:

I fixed it by adding a extra line in the gradle.properties file

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_111
```

Answer (score 0):

**CHANGE YOUR BUILD TOOL**

Go to options (ctrl + alt + s) and select tabs like in image, and change JRE to your actual i.e. `jdk1.8.0_111` (if you have few options, try to select them and run your app):

[image]

**IF IT IS NOT WORKING, WE ARE GOING FURTHER :D**

**Android Studio**

1. Close Android Studio
2. Go to you Android Studio directory and run `studio64.exe` instead `studio.exe`
3. Check if error still exists.

default dir for Android Studio: `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin`

[image]

**InteliJ IDEA**

same steps, run `idea64.exe` instead `idea.exe`

default (my) dir for Android Studio:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.3\bin`

[image]

Comment: Sorry im using intelliJ IDEA

Comment: I updated answer, check it out and tell me if it is working.

Comment: Go to project structure in Inteli (shift+ctrl+alt+s) select project, and select project sdk to 1.8 if it still not working post your gradle file

Comment: Still doesn't work but ill update my question with my project structure, what gradle file do you mean?

Comment: your `build.gradle` file you can see it in your structure. Post its content.

Comment: I posted it but the layout is kinda weird

Comment: ok i edited top of my answer, check it and tell me if it works, i have different ideas :D

Comment: Heey thanks but i think i found a problem, look at the last picture i posted there is no Java Home defined

Comment: Yeah, you can set JAVA_HOME `environment variable` or just pick one of 3 options and check if it works, it should work with second one, but check all 3 of them. But setting JAVA_HOME is good idea.

Comment: I found the solution :) ill add it in post